# power and fusing for first mains-powered project (100x WS2811 (RGB LED))

Tags: mains, grounding, fuses, ws2811

I'm a software guy who's done simple Arduino projects powered by a computer but doing my first project which involves mains/"wall" power.  Working backwards:

2x 50-LED chains of WS2811 addressable LED's will be controlled by a FadeCandy.  (A tiny controller that takes instruction over USB, then tells the LEDs what to do.)  This half I have no problem with or questions about.

But the LED's are power hungry.  18.5mA per color, for 55.5mA per light, x 100, = 5.55 amps.

I've got a S-100-5 power supply that takes in wall power (100-240VAC) and outputs 5V20A.  So lots of headroom there, apparently.

I have a fuse holder and 6A fuses (just say UEC 6A).  Would I put this on the DC side  or AC side?  Or is this unneeded such a project?  I'm OK at soldering in electrical guitars and electronics but I never worked with AC power before and am worried that just one stray whisker of wire will short or arc or something.

Finally, in Japan we don't have polarized plugs or three-prong plugs so I don't know which side is hot and which side is neutral.  Does it matter, as long as I don't touch the power supply?  (And it's in a plastic case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fuse is first and foremost to protect the wiring. It then offers you some protection against dropped bits of wire if you are 'adjusting live'. But where semi-conductors are involved, it's unlikely to protect the equipment itself.

Your wiring from wall to PSU must be fuse protected, consistent with the size of wire you are using. 'Soldering for electric guitars', while a good skill, is not really sufficient qualification for dealing with mains-side wiring. You need to add extra care, and complying with the mains regulations for your region. If your wiring from wall to PSU is large enough to be protected by the fuse that you *will* have back in your distribution fuse box, say a 10A distribution fuse and 1mm2 wiring, then you do not *need* a mains fuse. If you want an additional lower value mains-side fuse, then buy a fusable plug, or shrouded fuse holder, or mount the fuse securely (not hot-melt glue) inside your plastic box. A 6A fuse will be adequate for down to 0.5mm2 conductor. A smaller fuse, down to 1A even, will be better at offering some slight protection to the PSU as well.

That particular power supply is protected against overcurrent on the output, as will the vast majority of SMPSs be. This means it's unlikely to blow a mains-input fuse without itself being in trouble first. It also means you don't need an output fuse if your DC wiring is at least 2mm2. A 6A fuse, for a 5.5A load is a bit 'close', and might run hot, drop excessive voltage, and nuisance blow. If you do want to fuse your DC side, then 10A, or a 6A fuse on each chain, might be better.

Comment: Depending on how OP uses color in his RGB LEDs, most of the time he is going to be far from 5.5A. While I agree its very close, he might be fine.

Comment: My original mental image was just unsynchronized fireflies here and there, in traditional-looking red, green, and warm white.  That said once I get it going its possible I'd turn them all on full.